# Dart - Pass Interface as parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking for a similar solution for passing interface as paremeter in a function like Kotlin has:

```
test(object: Handler {
    override fun onComplete() {

    }
})
```

The only thing I find for Dart is using **implements** on the class, which is fine, but not what I need.

My approach so far has been making abstract class:

```
abstract class AuthListener{
  void onChange(AuthState authState);
}
```

Triggering of listener:

```
isSignedInListener(AuthListener authListener){
    FirebaseAuth.instance
        .authStateChanges()
        .listen((User user) {
      if (user == null) {
        return authListener.onChange(AuthState.SIGNED_OUT);
      } else {
        return authListener.onChange(AuthState.SIGNED_IN);
      }
    });
  }
```

And now I need to listen for the response, which is where I need some help:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function and use it as a callback (pass to methods etc.).

Function can be placed into variable:

```dart
  Function(AuthState authState) callback;
```

or as argument:

```dart
void isSignedInListener(Function(AuthState authState) callback) {}

auth.isSignedInListener((authState) {
  // do something here
});
```